# span styles override !important from parent

Tags: html, css

Has anyone an idea why this `span` inside of an `a` override the `!important` red color?

```css
a {
  color: red !important;
}

span {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="/test">
  <span>Test</span>
</a>
```

Comment: this is a scope rule. try as `a * {color: red !important;}` and see.

Comment: @dgknca Oh I didn't no that there was some kind of scope for `color`. Is there a way to fix it without using `a span {}`?

Comment: you are not overriding anything. You are selecting the span and applying color to it. The `a` selector is irrelevant and doesn't apply to span